# Set Size for jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

By default, jQuery Mobile fills the entire width of the screen. Is there a way to specify the size that jQuery Mobile should fill, such as providing an element to fill?

Answer (score 3):

Just set this line in your CSS file. Make it really easy. Change max-width to width if prefer.

.ui-page {
     max-width: 500px;
}

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify this through CSS...

For example:

CSS

```
#wrapper {width:95%}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div id="wrapper">
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Page content goes here.</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You can also do this dynamically by:

```
$("div[data-role='page']").css('width',$("#container_element").innerWidth()+"px");
```

Comment: Specifying the width on `#wrapper` does not work since the `data-role="page"` div has `position:absolute`. The jQuery snippet you provided does change the width, but it stays on the top-left corner of the page, regardless of where its container lies.

Comment: Not to mention that's working around that framework that jQuery Mobile has provided. No need to add additional wrappers or classes when you can just use the ones that are already there.

Answer (score 0):

The size is automatic. If you create a `div` outside the page div and set it to float and width in pixels - it should display correctly next to the page div.